# Nested map statements in Clojure don't evaluate properly, seems related to LazySeq

Tags: clojure, nested, boolean-logic, lazy-sequences, map-function

I have written a function in Clojure that is supposed to take a logical expression and return an equivalent expression where all `not` statements act directly on variables, like so:

```
(not (and p q r))
```

becomes

```
(or (not p) (not q) (not r))
```

It uses De Morgan's laws to push the `not`s inwards, and if a `not` acts directly on another `not` statement, they cancel out. The code looks like this:

```
(defn transform [expr]
    (if
        (list? expr)
        (if
            (=
                'not
                (first expr)
            )
            (if
                (list? (nth expr 1))
                (if
                    (=
                        'not
                        (first (nth expr 1))
                    )
                    (transform (first (rest (first (rest expr)))))
                    (if
                        (=
                            'and
                            (first (nth expr 1))
                        )
                        (cons 
                            'or 
                            (map
                                transform
                                (map
                                    not-ify
                                    (rest (first (rest expr)))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        (if
                            (=
                                'or
                                (first (nth expr 1))
                            )
                            (cons
                                'and 
                                (map
                                    transform
                                    (map
                                        not-ify
                                        (rest (first (rest expr)))
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                            expr
                        )
                    )
                )
                expr
            )
            expr
        )
        expr
    )
)
```

The problem lies in this part:

```
(map
    transform
    (map
        not-ify
        (rest (first (rest expr)))
    )
)
```

The first `map` statement uses a function `not-ify` (excuse the pun) to basically put a `not` before each statement. That part works. However, the output doesn't work with the `map transform`, although the `map transform` part works by itself. Let me show you:

If I write the following in the REPL:

```
(def expr '(not (and q (not (or p (and q (not r)))))))


(map
    not-ify
    (rest (first (rest expr)))
)
```

I get the output `((not q) (not (not (or p (and q (not r))))))`

If I then take that output and run `(map transform '((not q) (not (not (or p (and q (not r)))))))`, I get the output `((not q) (or p (and q (not r))))`. So far so good.

However if I run it all at once, like so:

```
(map
    transform
    (map
        not-ify
        (rest (first (rest expr)))
    )
)
```

I get this output instead: `((not q) (not (not (or p (and q (not r))))))`.

If run

```
(def test1
    (map
        not-ify
        (rest (first (rest expr)))
    )
)
(map transform test1)
```

I also get `((not q) (not (not (or p (and q (not r))))))`.

However if I run

```
(def test2 '((not q) (not (not (or p (and q (not r)))))))
(map transform test2)
```

I once again get the correct result: `((not q) (or p (and q (not r))))`.

My guess is that this is somehow related to the `map not-ify` output (`test1`) having the type `LazySeq`, while if I manually type the input (`test2`) it becomes a `PersistentList`. I've tried running `(into (list))` on `test1` to convert it to a `PersistentList`, as well as `doRun` and `doAll`, with no results. Can I somehow stop my `map not-ify` statement from returning a `LazySeq`?

Comment: `map` will always return a lazyseq.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for how I can solve the problem then? Is it not possible to have nested `map` statements?

Comment: Is this how `notify` is defined?: `(defn not-ify [expr] (list 'not expr))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use `seq?` instead of `list?`

Here is how I would implement it:

```
(defn push-not-down [expr]
  (if (and (seq? expr) (seq? (second expr)))
    (let [[outer-op & [[inner-op & inner-args] :as outer-args] :as expr] expr]
      (if (= 'not outer-op)
        (condp = inner-op
          'and (cons 'or (map #(push-not-down (list 'not %)) inner-args))
          'or (cons 'and (map #(push-not-down (list 'not %)) inner-args))
          'not (first inner-args)
          expr)
        (if (#{'or 'and} outer-op)
          (cons outer-op (map push-not-down outer-args))
          expr)))
    expr))

(deftest push-not-down-test
  (testing "Not or and not and are transformed to and not and or not"
    (is (= '(or (not :a) (not :b))
           (push-not-down
             '(not (and :a :b)))))
    (is (= '(and (not :a) (not :b))
           (push-not-down
             '(not (or :a :b))))))
  (testing "Double nots cancel"
    (is (= :a
           (push-not-down
             '(not (not :a))))))
  (testing "The rules work together in complex combinations"
    (is (= '(and :a (and :b (not :c)))
           (push-not-down
             '(and (not (not :a)) (not (or (not :b) :c))))))
    (is (= '(or (or (and (not :a))))
           (push-not-down
             '(or (or (and (not :a))))))))
  (testing "Nested expressions that don't fit the rules are preserved"
    (is (= '(not (inc 1))
           (push-not-down
             '(not (inc 1)))))
    (is (= '(inc (or 2 1))
           (push-not-down
             '(inc (or 2 1)))))))
```

For forms and expressions, there is no significant difference between a list or a sequence. Alternatively if you did want to preserve listiness, you just need to be a bit more thorough in converting sequences to lists :)

Comment: Thanks! This really helped push me over the hill.
Your example looks great, unfortunately I don't really know Clojure very well; It just happens that my discrete maths course has computer assignments in Clojure, without much more than a tutorial of the basics, so half of your code looks like gibberish to me. :P

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, ...

First, let's define what a logical `inverse` becomes:

```
(def opposite {'and 'or, 'or 'and})

(defn inverse [expr]
  (let [default (list 'not expr)]
    (if (seq? expr)
      (let [[op & args] expr]
        (if (= op 'not)
          (first args)
          (cons (opposite op) (map inverse args))))
      default)))
```

Let's test it:

```
(map inverse ['p '(not p) '(and a b) '(and (not a) b)])
;((not p) p (or (not a) (not b)) (or a (not b)))
```

It short-circuits double negatives as well as doing the [DeMorgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) thing.

Now we can express the transformation:

```
(defn transform [expr]
  (if (seq? expr)
    (let [[op & args] expr]
      (if (= op 'not)
        (inverse (first args))
        (cons op (map transform args))))
    expr))
```

For example,

```
(transform '(not (and p q r)))
;(or (not p) (not q) (not r))
```

- Where it finds a `not`, it returns the `inverse` of the argument.
- Otherwise, it reconstructs the expression, transforming
  sub-expressions where it can, just as `inverse` does.

If we're not fussed about transforming sub-expressions, we can simplify to

```
(defn transform [expr]
  (or (and (seq? expr)
           (let [[op & args] expr]
             (if (= op 'not) (inverse (first args)))))
      expr))
```

---

- I find pulling out the `inverse` manipulation easier to follow.
- In the simple `transform`, I've played with `and` and `or` and 
  one-armed `if` to avoid repeating the do-nothing case that weighs
  down OP's text.

How does this relate to [@TimothyPratley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367496/1562315)?

- I shamelessly stole his observation on using `seq?` instead of
  `list?`.
- His throws an exception on unrecognised operations. Mine just makes
  them `nil`.
- I've factored the `and`s and `or`s into a single case.